# React Material-UI Injecting withStyles not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to inject styles within same file below, but it's not working. No styles showing...

Is this the best way to inject styles? So we don't create a gigantic one CSS file for all CSS? or does it duplicate a lot of CSS we write since this page will be imported into the main component like couple other components will be pulled there... What do you guys think?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

// Styles
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        overflowX: 'auto',
        backgroundColor: red,
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 700,
    },
    row: {
        '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        },
    },
});

class UserDataTable extends Component {
    render(props) {
        const { classes } = this.props; 

        return (
            <div id="UserDataTable">
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>F</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>j</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>S</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>p</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>1</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>2</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>3</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>4</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(UserDataTable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling works fine except you had `backgroundColor: red` instead of `backgroundColor: "red"`.

[image: Edit 92q8y8rqow]

Comment: You've got to be kidding me! Gotcha! Also minorly, I was trying to get the header of the list to show up with darker background like here, why is it not? https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/ (under customized tables)

Comment: You don't have any code included to accomplish that. In the demo that is done using: `const CustomTableCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  head: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}))(TableCell);` and then using CustomTableCell in the header.

Comment: Can I not get it work by simply doing this? 
    TableHead: {
        backgroundColor: "black",
        color: "white",
    },

Comment: In some quick experimentation, that works for `backgroundColor`, but `color` doesn't seem to work reliably unless specified on the `TableCell`.